# Accessing $post variable from template part

Tags: posts, templates, page-template, variables, get-template-part

Here is a section of code that I have in a template file — to display sub-navigation if the page has child-pages:

```
<?php // display sub-nav if page has children ?>
<?php $children = get_pages(array('child_of' => $post->ID)); ?>
<?php if (count($children)) : ?>

    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">

        <?php foreach ($children as $val) : ?>
            <li role="presentation">
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($val->ID); ?>"><?php echo $val->post_title; ?></a>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

    </ul>
```

The code works fine when in the template file `page.php`, but if I put it all into a new file — `nav.php` and then include it with `<?php get_template_part( 'include', 'nav' ); ?>` then it stops working.

How can I set it so that the `$post` variable still works? Do I need to do something with global variables?

Comment: Where is nav.php located in your theme? (Is it in the root directory of the theme or a subdirectory?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is your file name is 'include-nav.php' or it is placed inside 'include' folder ?

if not then simply call it by passing name of **nav.php**

```
<?php get_template_part( 'nav' ); ?>
```

you don't have to pass include keyword to call template.

Hope this help :)

Comment: turns out I actually forgot to include the `include-` at the start of my filename for the template part! got it working now thanks

Answer (score 1):

`get_template_part()` calls your template file via `require()` but it does this inside of a function call. This means, it happens in a new variable scope. To make `$post` accessible again just use the `global` keyword.

```
<?php 
global $post;
$children = get_pages(array('child_of' => $post->ID)); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Existing variables will be accessible from within the included template if you wrap `locate_template()` inside an `include` statement:

```
include( locate_template( 'nav.php' ) );
```